# PHP echo date_format produces expects parameter 1 error

Tags: php

I have a standard PHP echo `echo $userinfo['ExpDate'];` that outputs a date like this 2016-05-13 00:00:00

I altered this echo statement to use date_format:

```
echo date_format($userinfo['ExpireDate'],"m/d/Y");
```

and I now get this error: 
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface

Comment: Have you tried `date('m/d/Y', strtotime($userinfo['ExpireDate']))`?

Comment: Because `$userinfo['ExpDate']` is a string, and `date_format()` expects a first argument of a DateTime object when used procedurally: `echo date_format(new DateTime($userinfo['ExpireDate']),"m/d/Y");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would use**

```
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($userinfo['ExpireDate']));
```

Comment: These seems the most efficient as it achieves the desired result in one line of code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
$date=date_create($userinfo['ExpireDate']);
echo date_format($date,"m/d/Y");
```

Check these

1. [PHP `date_create()` Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_create.asp)
2. [PHP `date_format()` Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp)

Comment: I would ***highly*** recommend linking to PHP Manual rather than w3Fools website.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php

Comment: Thanks @martin. It's easy to understand W3Schools rather php.net. but i'm agree with you

Answer (score 1):

PHP `date_format` requires first parameter as Object `date_format(object,format);`

**Try this:**

```
$date=date_create(userinfo['ExpireDate']);
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d H:i:s");
```